# Microphone is not working on Acer Nitro 5 Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, microphone, acer

I have Acer Nitro 5 Laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 OS 
This laptop has Digital microphone which is working fine. But I want my Earphone's internal microphone to be working.

I have dual boot installation and on windows I can switch from digital to normal microphone but not in ubuntu

I tried different methods like configuring alsa, reinstalling pulse audio but none of them worked.

I can hear from the earphone but can not use it as an input device.

Please help me with this situation because in future if digital microphone doesn't work I might need to work with headset microphone.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How does the !earphone! connect to the computer. 3.5, USB, Bluetooth? BTW Never heard of an earphone.